# Zend_Form_Element_File the move_uploaded_file function don't return anything

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload, zend-form

I am trying to upload a picture. I have Form_Zend and I use:

```
        $image = new Zend_Form_Element_File('image');

    $image->setLabel('Upload an avatar:')
            ->setMaxFileSize(8388608)
           // ->setDestination('./usersImages')
            ->setDescription('Click Browse and choose an image');
    $image->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
    $image->addValidator('Size', false, 8388608);
    $image->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif');

    $this->addElement($image, 'image');
```

My controller action code:

```
if ($form->image->isUploaded()) {
                            $values = $form->getValues();
                            $source = $form->image->getFileName();

                            $extention = substr($source, strrpos($source, '.', -1));

                            $date = date('mdYhisa', time());

                            $new_image_name = 'avatar_' . $date . '_' . $idUser . $extention;

    $destination = "C:\\xampp\\tmp\\Srututututut.png";

                            $image_saved = move_uploaded_file($source, $destination);

                            if ($image_saved) {

                                $data = array(
                                    'img' => $new_image_name,
                                );
                                $userDT->update($data, 'id=' . $idUser);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

But this move_uploaded_file is not returning nothing :/
What I have done:

1. Checked if the file is uploading - yes it is in: `C:\xampp\htdocs\Story\public\usersImages (if I set destination in this form element) or
   C:\xampp\tmp (if I dont set it)`
2. I was wondering about access to this folders but if it save there this images I think it has rights but I set in the apache:

   `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/Story/public/usersImages">
   Allow from All
   </Directory>`
3. I was even tried use this function only in C:\xampp\tmp folder:

   `$source: C:\xampp\tmp\database.png
   $destination: C:\xampp\tmp\Srututututut.png`

And still nothing :/

Do You have any suggestions?

Comment: What it says `var_dump($image_saved)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is with `$source = $form->image->getFileName();`. The reason is that it will return a name of the file uploaded rather than where it was uploaded to (i.e. its temporary localization).

Thus, I think your source should be as follows:

```
$fileInfo = $mainForm->image->getTransferAdapter()->getFileInfo();
$source   = $fileInfo['image']['tmp_name'];

// to check if the source really points to the uploaded file.
var_dump(file_exists($source));
```

Comment: This $source returns: $source: C:\xampp\tmp\database.png
as I checked it too :/
This var_dump(file_exists($source)); returns: bool(true)
:/ I have no idea where is mistake:/

Comment: @canimbenim. So I would suggest trying to use 'rename' function instead of 'move_uploaded_file'.

Comment: yes, but I need to copy it to different folder :/ Ok I will try to copy it and if it will not work I will look for different solution, dzieki Marcin ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I have no idea why this function is not working. I have changed my idea to set the $form->image destination first in the controller and then rename it and it is working.
Thanks for help guys ;D